# how do I read a file in desktop on esp8266 micropython?

Tags: text-files, micropython

I using the mac os and thonny micropython ide.

the file is called graph.txt on the desktop.

when i try reading it from the micropython ide, it gives the error:

```
file = open("graph.txt")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] ENOENT
```

when i try with the full file path it obviously still gives the same error. and when i write a new file, it is always empty and is not linked to the external files.

im expecting to cast the list inside the text file into a variable for my program to use.

Comment: the microcontroller has no direct access to the host computer's filesystem. It's like trying to access a file on a totally different computer. they just don't share the same files.

Comment: or is there any other way to transfer a list from a python file (that cannot run on thonny) into a micropython file ?

Comment: for uploading files, the [docs](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/tutorial/filesystem.html#accessing-the-filesystem-via-webrepl) suggest the [webREPL](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/tutorial/repl.html#webrepl-a-prompt-over-wifi) can interact with the filesystem on the 8266.